# Print center of faces for all objects

Tags: python, bmesh

I am trying to write a simple script that should print the location of the center of the faces of all objects in the scene. I understand that the easiest way is to use bmesh, but I am having some troubles. Here the code:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

for cube in bpy.context.selected_objects:
     cube.select_set(cube.type == "MESH")
     #print(cube.type) ---- it gives MESH as output
     bm = bmesh.new()
     bm.from_mesh(cube)
     for f in bm.faces:
        p=bpy.context.object.matrix_world @ f.calc_center_median()
        print(p)
```

The error is related to the fact that `cube` apparently is not a mesh, even though I have the command `cube.select_set(cube.type == "MESH")` at the beginning of the loop. Note that the commented line prints "MESH" as output. Any suggestions?

Comment: use `bm.from_mesh(cube.data)` the data part is the mesh data of the cube object.

Comment: That worked, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While the `cube` is the object, it's mesh data is stored in `cube.data`. Don't forget to free the allocated memory from the bmesh to avoid memory leaks. And to avoid too much newly allocated memory, you can recycle the bmesh object.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

bm = bmesh.new()

for o in bpy.context.selected_objects:
     bm.clear()
     bm.from_mesh(o.data)
     print(o.name)
     for f in bm.faces:
        p = bpy.context.object.matrix_world @ f.calc_center_median()
        print(p)

bm.free()
```

Comment: I actually found out that the correct code is `p=o.matrix_world @ f.calc_center_median()`. Using `bpy.context.object.matrix_world` gives wrong results.

Comment: Is the use of `bm.clear()` and `bm.free` mandatory?

Comment: if you reuse the bmesh and don't do a `bmesh.clear`, it will add another mesh on each succeeding iteration. on the first iteration it's still empty. but on the second iteration the previous mesh is loaded so we need to clear it. `bmesh.free` is mandatory because i think when you do a `new` it is doing an internal memory allocation (in C language `void *malloc(size_t size);`) since it is C-based and this always needs to be freed (`void free(void *pointer);`) or else you run into a memory leak.

Comment: but if your meshes are very small i guess you can just stick with doing a `bmesh.new` inside the `for` loop but then you need to free it at the end of each iteration. but i think it is best practice to be code efficient and memory efficient since memory allocation does come with a performance overhead especially in huge meshes.

Comment: What about if I put the command `bm=bmesh.new()` inside the `for` loop?

Comment: yeah see my previous comment :)

Comment: Ah, cool. We were writing at the same time :) Thanks for the help!

Comment: no problem~! :D